# SimpleXml attributes not showing for element with no children

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<STATUS_LIST>
    <ORDER_STATUS SORDER_CODE="SO001" ASSOCIATED_REF="001">
        <INVOICES>
            <INVOICE INVOICE_CODE="???">SOMETHING</INVOICE>
        </INVOICES>
    </ORDER_STATUS>
</STATUS_LIST>
```

When I run the following code:

```
$statuses = simplexml_load_string($result); //Where $result is my XML

if (!empty($statuses))
{
    foreach ($statuses as $status)
    {
        foreach ($status->INVOICES as $invoice)
        {
            echo (string)$invoice->attributes()->INVOICE_CODE;   
        }
    }
}
```

I step through this code and I **can** see the attributes against `ORDER_STATUS` but I **can't** see the attributes against `INVOICE`. I can however see the value `SOMETHING` against invoice.

Any idea what could cause this?

**Update**

After some testing, I can get the attributes to show if I add an element into the `INVOICE` element, so if I use this xml instead it will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<STATUS_LIST>
    <ORDER_STATUS SORDER_CODE="SO001" ASSOCIATED_REF="001">
        <INVOICES>
            <INVOICE INVOICE_CODE="???"><TEST>tester</TEST></INVOICE>
        </INVOICES>
    </ORDER_STATUS>
</STATUS_LIST>
```

So it **has** to have an element inside to pick up the attributes!?

Comment: Adding the extra `TEST` element is not what fixed this. Perhaps you also changed your PHP? Examples without: http://codepad.viper-7.com/4eL9s9 and with: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Cbyrsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with the element having no content, you simply have your loops defined slightly wrong.

When you write `foreach ($status->INVOICES as $invoice)`, SimpleXML will loop over every child of the `$status` element which is called `INVOICES`; in this case there will always be exactly one such element. But what you actually wanted is to loop over all the *children* of that element - the individual `INVOICE` nodes.

To do that you can use one of the following:

- `foreach ($status->INVOICES->children() as $invoice)` (loop over all child nodes of the first, and in this case only, `INVOICES` element)
- `foreach ($status->INVOICES[0]->children() as $invoice)` (the same, but being more explicit about selecting the first `INVOICES` node)
- `foreach ($status->INVOICES[0] as $invoice)` (actually does the same again: because you've specifically selected one node, and then asked for a loop, SimpleXML assumes you want its children; this is why `foreach($statuses as $status)` works as the outer loop)
- `foreach ($status->INVOICES->INVOICE as $invoice)` (loop over only child nodes called `INVOICE`, which happens to be all of them)

Personally, I would rewrite your sample loop as below:

```
foreach ($statuses->ORDER_STATUS as $status)
{
    foreach ($status->INVOICES->INVOICE as $invoice)
    {
        echo (string)$invoice['INVOICE_CODE'];   
    }
}
```

[Here's a live demo to prove that that works.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/74PflP)

Comment: Yes, I found this was the case later on but didn't get a chance to update the answer. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10248125/loading-xml-using-simplexml-doesnt-return-attributes-on-some-elements), "SimpleXML doesn't allow attributes and text on the same element."  It's pretty ridiculous, and I couldn't find any official coverage of that fact, but it seems true.  Lame.  It's valid XML.  I know Perl SimpleXML reads it fine.

Comment: I was just reading that post. I agree it's pretty stupid .. Going to work on a work around now.

Comment: If you look at the past question, you will see that it was in fact wrong, and the data was later accessed fine.

Comment: Or, to be more accurate, it was discovered to be a problem with converting to an array / JSON representation, which is not what SimpleXML was designed for, and is not what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I did look at the past question and it confirms exactly what I said- "SimpleXML doesn't allow attributes and text on the same element."  The only way the poster got around it was to add another extraneous element to his XML (he called it "<VALUEPATH>") just to get SimpleXML to work.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed Check the answers rather than taking that comment at face value. The OP's own answer, posted later, says "As MrCode suggested, the attributes were accessible. The problem I was in the serialisation of the SimpleXML object into another format." Since this question isn't about serialisation, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the record (PHP 8.1)

```php
$xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<STATUS_LIST>
    <ORDER_STATUS SORDER_CODE="SO001" ASSOCIATED_REF="001">
        <INVOICES>
            <INVOICE INVOICE_CODE="???">SOMETHING</INVOICE>
        </INVOICES>
    </ORDER_STATUS>
</STATUS_LIST>';

$statuses = simplexml_load_string($xml);
var_dump($statuses)
```

result:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["ORDER_STATUS"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["SORDER_CODE"]=>
      string(5) "SO001"
      ["ASSOCIATED_REF"]=>
      string(3) "001"
    }
    ["INVOICES"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["INVOICE"]=>
      string(9) "SOMETHING"
    }
  }
}
```

The attribute INVOICE INVOICE_CODE="???" is not available.

so @Dan Goodspeed is right

Solution:

- patches? nope, it has been broken for years.
- regexp to change the string? yes, but it changes the semantics of the result

```php
$str = preg_replace('/<([^ ]+) ([^>]*)>([^<>]*)<\/\\1>/i', '<$1 $2><value>$3</value></$1>', $string);
```